# Using variable in the middle of named constant

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have language settings which replace strings in my application. In order to avoid magic strings, I have defined named constants but the problem is I need to inject a variable in the middle of it. For instance,

```
const language_settings = {
   en: {
     NOTIFICATION: 'Send notification to my phone',
     TIME_REMANING: `Remaining time ${seconds} seconds`
  },
  fr: {
    NOTIFICATION: 'Envoyer verification sur mon portable',
    TIME_REMANING: `Temps restant ${seconds} secondes`  
 }
}
export default language_settings;
```

Naturally, the above code throws exception because of undefined "seconds" variable. Also, I don't want to separate strings into two just because of this. Can I do this without any major modification?

Answer (score 3):

You can make them functions instead:

```
const language_settings = {
   en: {
     NOTIFICATION: 'Send notification to my phone',
     getTimeRemaining: seconds => `Remaining time ${seconds} seconds`
  },
  fr: {
    NOTIFICATION: 'Envoyer verification sur mon portable',
    getTimeRemaining: seconds => `Temps restant ${seconds} secondes`  
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way is to define your string like this:
"Remaining time $0 seconds"
And call .replace("$0", seconds) on it every time you use it.
I know a popular game called CS:GO does this.

Or find a template engine on NPM that does this nicer

But JS string templates (the backtick strings) are not made for this.
You can also use a function that takes a value and returns a generated string

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of one of the many [templating libraries](https://colorlib.com/wp/top-templating-engines-for-javascript/).

Here are some examples:

[mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)

```js
const language_settings = {
  en: {
     NOTIFICATION: 'Send notification to my phone',
     TIME_REMANING: 'Remaining time {{seconds}} seconds'
  },
  fr: {
    NOTIFICATION: 'Envoyer verification sur mon portable',
    TIME_REMANING: 'Temps restant {{seconds}} secondes'  
 }
};

const language = "en";
const template = language_settings[language].TIME_REMANING;
const context = { seconds: 42 };

console.log(Mustache.render(template, context));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mustache@4/mustache.min.js"></script>
```

[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#template)

```js
const language_settings = {
  en: {
     NOTIFICATION: _.template('Send notification to my phone'),
     TIME_REMANING: _.template('Remaining time <%= seconds %> seconds')
  },
  fr: {
    NOTIFICATION: _.template('Envoyer verification sur mon portable'),
    TIME_REMANING: _.template('Temps restant <%= seconds %> secondes')
 }
};

const language = "en";
const template = language_settings[language].TIME_REMANING;
const context = { seconds: "42" };

console.log(template(context));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/underscore@1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Object.defineProperty` to dynamically define object properties with getters/setters and then utilize those functions to set value of seconds dynamically.

Following snippet will print the values with `seconds` value 1 at first, when `seconds` is changed to 5, then the logged statements will print with 5.

```js
let seconds = 1;
const language_settings = {
   en: {
     NOTIFICATION: 'Send notification to my phone',
     
  },
  fr: {
    NOTIFICATION: 'Envoyer verification sur mon portable',      
 }
}

Object.defineProperty(language_settings.en, 'TIME_REMANING', {
  get : () => { return `Remaining time ${seconds} seconds`}
});
Object.defineProperty(language_settings.fr, 'TIME_REMANING', {
  get : () => { return `Temps restant ${seconds} secondes` }
  });


console.log(seconds, language_settings.en.TIME_REMANING, language_settings.fr.TIME_REMANING);

console.log('change second to 5');
seconds = 5;

console.log(seconds, language_settings.en.TIME_REMANING, language_settings.fr.TIME_REMANING);
```